When VNCserver started, XFCE says "X server already running on display" but no X server are actually running
I try to run VNC server with xfce
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
My xstartup file :
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
export DISPLAY=:0
dbus-launch --exit-with-session startxfce4 &

I run with : vncserver :0 -localhost no
And my log file I got :
admin@ip-172-31-1-53:~/.vnc$ tail ip-172-31-1-53\:0.log
[mi] mieq: warning: overriding existing handler (nil) with 0x562b2e0ee180 for event 3
3NI3X0 New Xtigervnc server 'ip-172-31-1-53:0 (admin)' on port 5900 for display :0.
3NI3X0 Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth,TLSVnc -passwd /tmp/tigervnc.MqKfs3/passwd ip-172-31-1-53:0 to connect to the VNC server.
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :0
xrdb: Connection refused
xrdb: Can't open display ':0'
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .
Type 'xfce4-session --help' for usage.

It says :  X server already running on display :0
But this is not true, there was no X server running anywhere before I tried to start VNCserver.
I did :
sudo rm -f /tmp/.X0-lock /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
admin@ip-172-31-1-53:~$ ps aux | grep X -> show nothing
admin@ip-172-31-1-53:~$ ps aux | grep xorg -> show nothing
rm -rf /home/admin/.cache/

admin@ip-172-31-1-53:~/.vnc$ nmap 127.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-10-24 09:29 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000082s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed tcp ports (conn-refused)
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds

But it still says X is running...(I also rebooted)
When I do : tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm      it works perfectly.
And when I start startxfce4 I don't have any error message...
Any ideas?
Thanks

I added the Ubuntu version
